# Why in Javascript is an extra set of parentheses used after .shift()?

Tags: javascript

In the following, why is (input) added after queue.shift()?

```
var puzzlers = [
  function ( a ) { return 8*a - 10; }, 
  function ( a ) { return (a-3) * (a-3) * (a-3); }, 
  function ( a ) { return a * a + 4; },
  function ( a ) { return a % 5; }
];

var start = 2;

var applyAndEmpty = function( input, queue ) {
  var length = queue.length;
  for(var i = 0; i<length; i++){
    input = queue.shift()(input);
  }
  return input;
};

alert(applyAndEmpty(start, puzzlers));
```

It's clear that moving input into the shift() parentheses, it returns the function itself instead of the correct value. But what are the guidelines for putting (input) after (I can't find documentation on this)?

Comment: The array it's operating on contains functions. Shift returns one of those functions. Adding parens immediately executes the returned function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the elements of the array are functions. Functions are objects in JavaScript; they can be passed around, stored in arrays and returned from other functions. You could write as:

```
var fn = queue[0]; // a function object
var input = fn(input); // execute the function
```

Now that you know about first class functions, another approach of doing a sequence (or a queue) is composition, where instead of executing a function, assign the value, then execute the next one, you'd create a function that is the composition of all other functions, given that their inputs and outputs match, for example:

```
function compose() {
  return [].reduce.call(arguments, function(f,g) {
    return function() {
      return g(f.apply(this, arguments));
    };
  });
};

var puzzle = compose.apply(null, puzzlers);
var result = puzzle(2);
console.log(result); //=> 3
```

Comment: `[].reduce.call(arguments, function(f,g){...`

Answer (score 0):

Like elclanrs said, the objects in your array are functions, here's an example

```
function yell(saying){
    alert(saying);
}

function whisper(secret){
    console.log(secret);
}

var waysOfSpeaking = [yell, whisper];

// let's yell
waysOfSpeaking[0]('DANGER');

// let's whisper
waysOfSpeaking[1]('I like you');
```